# How to write Ordered partition in a summation involving a huge expression

Tags: summation, partitions

$$b_n=\sum_{m=2}^{\lfloor\frac{n}{3}\rfloor}\left\{(-1)^m\frac{l_m}{m+1}\sum_{i_1+i_2+...+i_m=n}a^{(1)}_{i_1}a^{(2)}_{i_2}...a^{(m)}_{i_m}\right\}$$
The $i_k\geq3$, for any $k$. Here $a^{(k)}$ represents a variable and ${i_k}$ is just an indexing according to the partition of $n$.

P.S: Integer partition will not work. Ordered partition is required precisely.
How do we write this in Mathematica?

Comment: user74846  AFAIK ordered set partitions are simply set partitions plus permutations. If this is correct, you can get them by e.g.:  Flatten[Permutations /@ IntegerPartitions[4], 1]

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by *Ordered partition*? What have you tried?

Comment: use `FrobeniusSolve[ConstantArray[1,m],n]` to get indexes of the inner sum

Comment: @I.M., I'm looking for the same thing but the indexing should be greater or equal to 3. How do I modify?

Comment: @DanielHuber, yes that's right. I tried that code, but didn't work.. any other way?

Comment: @user74846 Hi, If I execute the code: "Flatten[Permutations /@ IntegerPartitions[4], 1]" I get the result: "{{4}, {3, 1}, {1, 3}, {2, 2}, {2, 1, 1}, {1, 2, 1}, {1, 1, 2}, {1, 1, 
  1, 1}}" I think this is correct. (Note I have MMA 12.1)

Comment: @DanielHuber, no doubt this result is true, but it's not working for higher values of n, even if I consider, say, 9. Completing the inner summation is not enough, it needs modification overall.

Comment: user74846 Could you please specify why you think it is not working for n==9.

Comment: @DanielHuber, I find the terms appearing with l_2 and l_3 are same. But in reality, the  homogenous terms of order 2 must appear with l_2 and of order 3 with l_3.

Comment: @user74846 I do not understand what you mean. Please indicate a term that is wrong and explain why it is wrong.

Comment: Do you want `FrobeniusSolve[ConstantArray[1,m],n-3m]+3` ?

Comment: @DanielHuber, For n=8
, I am getting, 1/3 (a[1]^6 + 5 a[1]^4 a[2] + 6 a[1]^2 a[2]^2 + a[2]^3 + 
    4 a[1]^3 a[3] + 6 a[1] a[2] a[3] + a[3]^2 + 3 a[1]^2 a[4] + 
    2 a[2] a[4] + 2 a[1] a[5] + a[6]) l[2]}, whereas what I was needing was : 1/3 (a[4]^2 + 2 a[3] a[5]) l[2]

Comment: @AndrewSwann, yes, that's right! thank you so much

Comment: @user74846 I was expecting an an ordered partition that is wrong.

Comment: @DanielHuber The ordered partition mentioned by you is correct, but when it comes to indices, its not working. Or perhaps I do not know how well it needs to be coded/modified for the given expression

Comment: @user74846 Well let me try  to state the problem, maybe there is a misunderstanding.  For m=8 we have e.g. a partition {5,2,1} and you want to turn this partition into term a5 a1 a1. This can be done by (using subscripts) by defining a function fu and applying it to :{5,2,1}:  fu = Function[x, Times @@ (Subscript[a, #] & /@ x)] ; fu[{5, 2, 1}] Note, this is a bit tricky, a function inside a function, but try to understand it. When you have a list of partitions  like e.g.: {{2, 2, 4}, {4, 2, 1, 1}} you would map fu onto this list like: fu /@ {{2, 2, 4}, {4, 2, 1, 1}}Note: "/@" means "Map".

Comment: @DanielHuber, first of all, the indices have to be greater or equal to 3 as specified earlier. Even if we do not have that condition, the partition {5,2,1} should correspond to a5 a2 a1. Right now ```FrobeniusSolve[ConstantArray[1,m],n-3m]+3``` is working well with the requirement

Answer (score 1):

As @I.M. suggested

```
FrobeniusSolve[ConstantArray[1,m],n]
```

with give all `m` tuples of indices at least `0` summing to `n`.  However, you have added the extra constraint that each index should be at least `3`.  Subtracting `3` from each index, we get that the sum should be `n-3m` instead and can construct your indices as

```
f[m_,n_] := FrobeniusSolve[ConstantArray[1,m],n-3m]+3
```

For example `n=12`, `m=3` yields

```
In[3]:= f[3,12]                                                                 

Out[3]= {{3, 3, 6}, {3, 4, 5}, {3, 5, 4}, {3, 6, 3}, {4, 3, 5}, {4, 4, 4}, 
 
>    {4, 5, 3}, {5, 3, 4}, {5, 4, 3}, {6, 3, 3}}
```

Answer (score 0):

This example builds a homogeneous polynomial with $m$ variables and total degree $n$.

$$p(m,n) = \sum_{i_1 + \dots + i_m = n} x_{1}^{i_1} \dots x_{m}^{i_m}$$

`Power`, can be converted to a two-indexed form.

```
ClearAll[index] ;
index[m_,n_] := FrobeniusSolve[ConstantArray[1,m],n] ;
(* m - number of variables *)
(* n - total monomial power *)
m = 2 ; n = 6 ; 
vars = Array[x,m] ;
list = index[m,n] ;
poly = Total[Map[Apply[Times],Transpose[vars^Transpose[list]]]]
poly /. Power[x[a_],b_] :> x[a,b]   /. x[a_] :> x[a,1]
m = 3 ;  n = 3 ; 
vars = Array[x,m] ;
list = index[m,n] ;
poly = Total[Map[Apply[Times],Transpose[vars^Transpose[list]]]]
poly /. Power[x[a_],b_] :> x[a,b]   /. x[a_] :> x[a,1]
```

Comment: There appears irresistibly many terms for higher values of n, which do not fall into the condition mentioned in the question. Though, the third variety of output is what I'm seeking for, given that the conditions satisfy. It messes up when I'm actually dealing with the actual summation that I want to code